# Genymotion virtual device does not start

Tags: virtualbox, android, genymotion

I have signed in to Genymotion website, downloaded the installation binary from funzone and installed it. Signed into the application with same credentials and created an Android appliance. When I try to start the Android device, a new Genymotion window is launched asking me to login again, instead of launching the Android device.

When I submit the credetials to newly launched window, it takes me to devices list again, and whenever I try to start the Android device, the same happens. I checked for the logs and found this.

```
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [warning] Cannot start: no license, and not in personal use. Starting launchpad.
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [info] Exiting
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] "Notifying launchpad of status change: f8a9c555-725f-4c54-b4ff-3541853c82e6 OFF"
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [warning] Failed to send message
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [warning] Template cache from "/home/anony/.Genymobile/Genymotion/templates/sharedTemplates.list" is outdated, ignoring it
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] Template list updated successfully
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "f8a9c555-725f-4c54-b4ff-3541853c82e6", "androvm_ip_management")
Logging activities to file: /home/anony/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2020-07-03T17:09:39+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "--machinereadable", "f8a9c555-725f-4c54-b4ff-3541853c82e6")
2020-07-03T17:09:40+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2020-07-03T17:09:40+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "--machinereadable", "f8a9c555-725f-4c54-b4ff-3541853c82e6")
2020-07-03T17:09:40+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2020-07-03T17:09:40+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] ==== STOPPING VIRTUAL DEVICE ====
2020-07-03T17:09:40+05:30 [Genymotion Player:25148] [debug] Exit status: 19 PlayerNS::ExitCode(NO_LICENSE)
```

It says `NO_LICENSE` but I checked `Personal use` while logging in.

I am on Ubuntu 18 and Virtualbox 5.2.34. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the exact same error. I am using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS version and downloaded the latest version of genymotion. I created a device successfully with android 8.0 and got the exact same error as you. Could you find the solution?

I have uninstalled completely and reinstalled again but still same error.

Seems like the genymotion is not able to read login credentials and personal use license from the file in our non-root user directory. That is why it was asking me to login everytime I started genymotion.

SOLUTION:- Start genymotion as root. It works and does not ask to login again.